# Ignore some links while crawling in splash browser with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am crawling JavaScript website using splash and scrapy which was previously working fine but as now they update their website now my splash browser stuck on 'https://s16.examplecdn.com/example/falcon/_next/static/1.0.1.320/pages/_error.js' page after downloading it and remain hang till we not kill it by manually. Please help me regarding this, or someone can tell me how we can just by pass this link so that it doesn't stuck here and go forward for other crawling.

Answer (score 1):

So sometimes some websites put up a defense for spiders and bots called **honey pots**. These traps usually send bots to a dead-end that they cannot escape from. When dealing with urls you want to make use of regular expressions to filter out urls that should be exempted while crawling the site and you can pass all urls through this check before your spider proceeds to the link or have your spider pass it if has disagreement with the pattern.

```
import re

.....

pattern = re.compile(^www.[\w\d].(com|org|net|ng)$) #create a url pattern here, you will have to edit this to suit your needs
for url in urls:
    match = pattern.search(url)
    if not match:
        continue
    else:
       #perform normal crawling/scraping activities
```

this is one way around those kind of links. Hope it helped

Comment: Hi @maestro.inc thanks for answer and I understand that i can do this kind of thing, but only here problem is splash network-manager not releasing control so i unable to filter this link. Otherwise, your answer is perfect. If you know something about to force splash to go forward if error occurs something like then please help.

Comment: personally I usually just go with the scrapy selenium third party package instead of splash(felt more comfortable with selenium and it proved somewhat more flexible) only downside is that it can be a little tricky to set up at first

Comment: When i use the selenium third party which works like the typical selenium package i usually just do a redirect back to the initial site with `driver.execute_script(f'windows.replace.location{'url i want to go to'}")` within a timeout or similar exception and keep the script running from there

Comment: Hi @maestro.inc  I have gone through this link 'https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium' and setup selenium with scrapy, And crawl some basic website with it, but when I go for crawling angular website (which I want to crawl) then it's not loading proper webpage. When I use it with selenium web driver and run through python code, my website is not load properly and it's loading...... but in normal browser it's loading correctly. That's why I was using splash because this kind of heavy website take time to load. Any other solution you can provide or some suggestion???

Comment: Have you tried running the selenium in headless mode or run custom JavaScript using lua when using scrapy splash

Comment: Yes, I have run lua script but in splash control is not returned for parsing, so how can I process html and all. In case of selenium webpage taking more time to load. so have u any other browser which can render javascript??

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i escape honey pots links in splash and scrapy. for this i wrote lua script like below

```
splash:on_request(function(request)
    if string.match(request.url,'^%l+://%w+.example.com') or 
       string.match(request.url,'^%l+://%w+[^%w]+%a+.example.com') then
       request.abort()
    end
    if string.match(request.url,'error.js') then
       print("## get error while page rendering ###")
       request.abort()
    end
end)
```

Here above code will drop that link if it matches specific pattern (honey pot links) or get error.js page while requesting.
**Second one condition is very import while rendering in splash because if u not handle these kind of js then splash rendering engine will hang and never give you control back**